# Excel number sequence

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a number sequencing formula in excel similar to a folder structure where each number can potentially contain many dots indicating which "folder" it lies within. For instance:

```
    1.0
        1.1
        1.2
            1.2.1
            1.2.2
            1.2.3
        1.3
    2.0 
        2.1
            2.1.1
            2.1.2
```

I have tried several different ways by using MAX formulas (for instance +MAX($A$1:B3)+1) and tried to combine these in different ways but I can's find a solution that works. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are these characters you want to have generated after a certain input? what is your input information? How is your spreadsheet structured? I have some ideas for how to build something, but this is a little too vague right now.

Comment: Is each of your data points in a new column? That will be overly difficult to automate as you will need formulas in all cells, or a macro that runs the risk of overwriting data present in columns further to the right.